# Merge [utf8] and [utf-8]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

Can we merge [utf8](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/utf8) and [utf-8](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/utf-8) & synonymize? They're obviously identical. I would merge [utf8](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/utf8) into [utf-8](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/utf-8), since it's usually written with a hyphen [(Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Done

```
updating post history, 89 rows affected
updating posts, 68 rows affected
updating PostTags associations, 65 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 0 rows affected
updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [utf-8] and [utf8] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
4 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
Tag Synonym utf8 -> utf-8 was approved!
Broadcasting tag-engine reload
```